# How to get mysql to throw an error on update for no rows matched?

Tags: mysql, c, libmysql

I want to know when an `UPDATE` query reports 0 rows matches. I'm using `libmysql`.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
char query[300] = {0};
snprintf(query, 300, "UPDATE `my_table` SET name='%s' WHERE id=%d",
         name, id);

if (mysql_query(db, query)) {
    printf("Error!\n");
}
```

Essentially what I need to know is whether or not there is a match for `id`. I know I can check that by doing a select, but is there another way?

Comment: Most implementations of mysql can provide a 'affected_rows'. I don't know libmysql but you should read through the docs and look if affected_rows is mentioned somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [mysql_affected_rows](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-affected-rows.html). This will return number of modified rows by the last query.

However, it may return just the rows actually modified. If you want to return matched row, you have to specify `CLIENT_FOUND_ROWS` in `mysql_real_connect`. Check the same page for details.

Comment: Thanks! `mysql_affected_rows` is exactly what I need.